# $_GET returns null from Ajax fetch()

Tags: php, ajax

So, I am making a trivia game. Here is my PHP code and my Ajax Code. The problem is, the variable $categoryName in my php code keeps returning null no matter what I do. As a result, in my JS code, when I try to fetch the url, I keep getting this error: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0
    at parse ()"

This code is not in a state of completion yet, but this issue is preventing me from moving forward. Any ideas? These are two different files on an AMPPS server

**PHP File**

```
/* Step 2:  Write a trivia.php code to read the .txt files (from particular category specified by the fetch()) and output as JSON.  You can use $_GET[“mode”], scandir and json_encode(). 


What you need to do is given the category query parameter from the trivia.js, create a random question  (e.g. using array_rand()) send it back to the browser.

*/

//handles category names
$triviafiles = "trivia/"; //questions and answers themselves
$files = scandir("trivia/");
$categories = implode('<br>', $files);
echo $categories;

//gets questions
$categoryName = strtolower($_GET["name"]); //always is null. Don't know why

$trivia = glob($triviafiles.$categoryName."/*.txt"); 
//categoryName still shows up as Null. Hardcoding a name in works, but that obviously defeats the purpose. 

foreach($trivia as $question){
    $answer = file_get_contents($question);
}

echo(json_encode(array("question" => $question, "answer" => $answer)));

?>
```

**JavaScript File**

```
window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    let showCat = document.getElementById("view-all");
    showCat.onclick = fetchCategories;
    let show_answer = document.createElement("button");
    show_answer.classList.add("controls");
    show_answer.innerHTML += "Show Answer";
    document.getElementById("question-view").append(show_answer);
//    show_answer.onclick = 

};



function displayCategories() {
    document.getElementById("categories-heading").className = null;
    document.getElementById("category-view").className = null;

}

function selectedText(category){
    let categories = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for(let i = 0; i<categories.length; i++){
        categories[i].classList.remove("selected-category");
    }
    category.classList.add("selected-category");
    category.onclick = showTrivia;
}


function fetchCategories() {     
    let hrx = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    hrx.onload = displayCategories;
    hrx.open("GET", "trivia.php?mode=category");
    hrx.send();
    hrx.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(hrx.readyState === 4 && hrx.status === 200) {
            let list = hrx.responseText;
            list=list.split("<br>");
            for (let i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
                let category = document.createElement("li");
                category.innerHTML += list[i];
                document.getElementById("categories").appendChild(category);
            }
        }

        let categories = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        for(let i = 0; i<categories.length; i++){
            categories[i].classList.remove("selected-category");
            categories[i].addEventListener("click",function(){selectedText(categories[i])}, false);
        }

    }
}

    //include this code, based on: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch
    function checkStatus(response){  
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
            return response.text();
        }else{
            return Promise.reject(new Error(response.status + ": " + response.statusText));
        } 
    }
function displayQuestion() {
    document.getElementById("question-view").className = null;
    document.getElementById("card").className = null;
}

function showTrivia() {
    let currentCategory = document.querySelector(".selected-category");
    console.log(currentCategory);
    let url = "trivia.php?mode=category";
    url += "&name=" + currentCategory.innerHTML;
    console.log(url);

     fetch(url, {method: "GET"})     
     .then(checkStatus)
     .then(JSON.parse) // main issue. Parsing error    
     .then(displayQuestion);

    }
```

Comment: The PHP code runs when the page is first loaded, but the AJAX fetch doesn't happen until the user clicks on the category. The initial load doesn't have `name=` in the URL.

Comment: @barmar, how would I get around this? I understand the error, but I don't know enough about PHP to understand how to make specific PHP calls in Ajax.

Comment: Separate out the pages for server-side AJAX (PHP) and the client-side AJAX (HTML & js). The client-side AJAX has the reference to call the server-side AJAX that won't run until you need it to.

Comment: @malovich, sorry, I didn't make it clear, these are already two separate files. Would it be as simple as making two separate PHP functions?

Comment: @LukeTheuma Ah, no. Right then, next thing I notice is that you're looking for a `name` on the $_GET but are only sending along a `mode`. Without sending the key the PHP code is looking for, it'll send a notice-level error and populate the missing key with `null` by default.

Comment: @malovich thanks for your response! When I print out the url the JS fetches, it's correct: trivia.php?mode=category&name=biology (or whatever other category the user selects)

Comment: Why do you use `XMLHttpRequest` in `fetchCategories()`, but `fetch()` in `showTrivia()`? Pick one way to do your AJAX requests and stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i can't comment yet, but here's my take:)
as others have explained, you have 2 AJAX calls to trivia.php

in the first one (when user clicks on "view-all") you don't specify name in the GET

in the second one (when user clicks on a specific category) you specify name in the GET

during the first load of trivia.php it's logical that $categoryName is null, because you don't specify it
are you sure you are also checking the second load of trivia.php? because it seems that $categoryName should be filled in that time.

Comment: Thanks! Question, would you recommend just making the url that from the get go? Something like hrx.open("GET", "trivia.php?mode=category&name=");

on the first load?

Comment: also, maybe I am not checking it, but I am unsure how to check the first vs second load.

Comment: that's why people are suggesting you use 2 separate php files.
1 for the first load, and the second one for the 2nd load

Comment: That did it! Thank you everyone!!